# Windows Mobile OS 8

Tags: windows, windows-mobile, emulation

**Is there any Online Emulator for Windows 8 mobile OS?**

*I want to check windows mobile os as demo so I search online couldn't found any mobile demo os for windows and non of my friends or colleges using windows mobile os so is there any?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Windows Mobile" and "Windows Phone" are totally different operating systems for mobiles.

The Windows Phone 8 emulator is part of the Visual studio 2012 (for Phone 8 and VS2013 for phone 8.1) express windows phone SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/download-phone-sdk

Development for Windows Mobile (6.x and CE 6) is done from VS2008 (or VS2005). The WM6.x SDK needs to be downloaded separately. But there are free stand-alone-device-emulator downloads: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee535724%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: thnx a lot for the basic idea you given me to clarify the diffrence

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware there is no such thing as Windows Mobile 8.  Windows Mobile essentially "died" after Windows Mobile 6.5.  It was later renamed to Windows Embedded Handheld.  Windows Phone has a version 8, but it is **much** different from Windows Mobile.

According to this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402563%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), the Windows Phone 8 emulator is installed with the Windows Phone 8 SDK.  Your friends and colleagues would need to install the SDK to get the emulator to run the program.

Comment: thnxa lot for the ansr and given me the idea